# How to compose tweet after integrating twitter in Ionic App

Tags: ionic3

I Integrated Twitter in my Ionic3 App. I want to tweet my images and text, but there is no any method to compose tweet .

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/twitter-connect/

```
 this.tweetConnect.login().then(data =>{})
```

Cordova mention `TwitterConnect.openComposer()` but it's not showing in Ionic